# Scale legend for leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible (or is there a plugin) which shows a legend of the current scale/zoom in one of the corners? I'm not sure if this is the correct English term so here is an image:

[image]

(google calls it id='scalecontrol' ;))

Of course it should only show up for the lower zoom levels as otherwise the distances of the northern and southern area would be too different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After knowing the correct name I was able to find it in [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-scale) or [here](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/scale-control/) or [older](https://github.com/jtreml/leaflet.customscale) [ones](https://leaflet.uservoice.com/forums/150880-ideas-and-suggestions-for-leaflet)